# MVC 3/Design Patterns issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, design-patterns, c#-4.0

I made a settings page for my website. On this page the user is presented with a bunch of site wide settings they can manipulate. I made it so when the user selects a setting the page will automatically run an ajax request to send the setting to the database. My question is in how I do this.

At first I just did calls to the repository. One call to get the data back, put it into a ViewModel then give that ViewModel to the View and the ajax controller just sent the settings back to the database. This way seemed like the best at first especially for unit testing purposes since I could just pass in a fake repository if needed. Then for the user to get a setting they just called the repository and pass in the setting name they want.

Then I had a bright idea. I made a singleton class called SiteWideSettings and each possible setting on the site was a property of the site. When SiteSettings is called for the first time all of the settings are loaded. When Set is called on any of the properties it will call the repository function to send the setting. Now with my Settings view I'm just passing in SiteWideViewOptions.Current and on the ajax call I'm updating the property that was changed. This is working for me however it's not very unit testable since I can't really pass in a repository to a singleton's constructor since its constructor is private. What I currently have is working fine but I just don't feel like it's the best solution and unit testing isn't really possible here.

I'm thinking of one of the following but not sure which is the best.

- Add a Repository property to the SiteWideSettings class
- Add a function to the SiteWideSettings class to pass in a repository
- Not use a singleton for this at all and just go back to what I was doing before I had this idea

Any comment on this would be greatly appreciated.

Note: I know. I know I'm doing unit testing wrong in this case because I didn't write my test first so please don't scold me for that.. I have already scolded myself and with my next task I won't do it again I promise :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Then I had a bright idea. I made a singleton class called
>   SiteWideSettings and..."

This sounds like a bad idea.  Let your database be ground-truth for what the settings are, not some in-memory cache that you now need to keep up to date.  Let your ORM do caching if you need it for performance otherwise you are just adding problems especially if you now try to run your site on more than one server.

If you want to simplify the controller so it has less 'set-up' and 'tear-down' code in it, use an IOC (e.g. Autofac) and inject any dependencies you need (e.g. a DataContext or a Repository) on a per-http-request basis.

Your action methods are now easier to test since you can simply instantiate your controller (injecting the dependencies manually using its constructor) and then call your method.

Comment: As far as keeping it up to date I'm not too worried about because all access to the SiteSettings data to or from the database will be done from this class.. You said there might be issues with running on multiple servers. I'm still not at the Sr. Dev level when it comes to web development so I'm curious what kind of issues would there be with having a cluster of webservers rather than one? 
The last development shop I was at we deployed to a cluster of webservers and I never had issues. I'm just curious what you've seen and how this situation could face issues. Thank you for the quick response

Comment: With a single server things are easy, you can cache stuff locally and not worry about it, but as soon as you have more than one system updating the database you'd need to deal with it.  More importantly, as you've realized, singletons have other issues, especially concerning testability.